# DSolve DAE echoing - no solution/response

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I am aware that there are lots of questions about this topic but they are all slightly different.
I am attempting to program a cybersecurity infection model and there are 4 states that a computer can be in. $x_{--}$ represents the percentage of computers within that state. I require an analytic solution.

This is currently the system I am attempting to find a solution for
$x'_{DI}(t) = x_{DS} q^D_{inf} v_{1} - x_{DI} q^D_{rec} + x_{DI} x_{DS} \beta_{DD} + x_{UI} x_{DS} \beta_{UD} + \lambda(x_{UI}u_{UI}-x_{DI}u_{DI})$
$x'_{DS}(t) = -x_{DS} q^D_{inf} v_{1} + x_{DI} q^D_{rec} - x_{DI} x_{DS} \beta_{DD} - x_{UI} x_{DS} \beta_{UD} + \lambda(x_{US}u_{US}-x_{DS}u_{DS})
 $
$x'_{UI}(t) = x_{US} q^U_{inf} v_{1} - x_{UI} q^U_{rec} + x_{DI} x_{US} \beta_{DU} - x_{UI} x_{US} \beta_{UU} + \lambda(x_{UI}u_{UI}-x_{DI}u_{DI})$
$x_{DS} + x_{DI} + x_{UI} + x_{US} = 1$

(View everything that doesn't begin with x as a constant).
This is what I have tried so far:

```
sol4 = DSolve[{xdi'[t] == 
 xds[t]*qdinf*v1 - xdi[t]*qdrec + xdi[t]*xds[t]*bdd + 
  xui[t]*xds[t]*bud + l*(xui[t]*uui - xdi[t]*udi), 

xds'[t] == - xds[t]*qdinf*v1 + xdi[t]*qdrec - xdi[t]*xds[t]*bdd - 
  xui[t]*xds[t]*bud + l*(xus[t]*uus - xds[t]*uds), 

xui'[t] == 
 xus[t]*quinf*v1 - xui[t]*qurec + xdi[t]*xus[t]*bdu + 
  xui[t]*xus[t]*buu - l*(xui[t]*uui - xdi[t]*udi), 

xui[t] + xus[t] + xdi[t] + xds[t] == 1}, {xdi[t], xds[t], xui[t], 
xus[t]}, t][[1]]
```

But unfortunately, I am only getting an echo output at the moment and no solution is being produced (just a repeat of the code).

I would very much appreciate your help! You guys have saved my dissertation :)

Comment: In general, `DSolve` can solve only equations with known solutions.  Is there reason to believe that an analytical solution exists?

Comment: Even if an analytical solution exists, it is not guaranteed that *Mathematica* (or any particular package) can find it. You might like to try Maple as well. If neither give you a result, you can say in your dissertation that you have reason to believe that no analytical solution exists, and therefore that you proceed numerically. By the way, "analytic" and "analytical" are not the same thing. From context I assume you mean "analytical", but you should clarify this in case our assumption is not correct.

Comment: Thank you very much, I shall try Maple first - hopefully I can find a student license for it. Do you believe Matlab could do this?

Comment: `DSolve` returns so fast that it must know it can't solve it.  (I wish it would say so, though.)

Comment: you are trying to resolve a non-linear equation, all the terms with xdi[t]*xds[t] that is. Save a few known cases they are not solvable analytically.  I would study the model numerically for different cases, say what happens when the initial conditions are such and such.  Don't know who required an analytical solution but doesn't really know about differential equations.

Comment: and don't even try matlab, it's name comes from matrices laboratory, so they are not particularly good at solving equations. Maple maybe, I know they still use it in general relativity to solve stuff.

Comment: @tsuresuregusa Which duplicates did you find?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard [link1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39112/no-response-from-dsolve?rq=1) [link2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60700/no-solution-with-dsolve?rq=1) both with no answers. This is from the documentation "For nonlinear differential equations, only rather special cases can usually ever be solved in terms of standard mathematical functions. Nevertheless, DSolve includes fairly general procedures which allow it to handle almost all nonlinear differential equations whose solutions are found in standard reference books."

Comment: Thank you very much for your help guys, I shall set some numbers for my parameters and if it doesn't work, I will make angry faces at my supervisor